# how do I install opencv4.0 on 18.10?

Tags: software-installation, compiling, opencv

I have been trying to install opencv4.0.1 on ubuntu for a few weeks now. I have followed the [opencv installation instructions](https://docs.opencv.org/4.0.1/d7/d9f/tutorial_linux_install.html)
and I am able to make and compile the library, yet after installation, pkgconfig still cant find the library, and when I try to build programs, I get things like missing library errors.

```
$ pkg-config --cflags opencv
Package opencv was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `opencv.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'opencv' found
```

Comment: Did you set `PREFIX=/usr/local` - or somewhere else (perhaps somewhere in your home directory)?

Comment: when I compiled used the flag: -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [this issue](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/13154), OpenCV dropped support for pkg-config. However, this can be added as follows:

**Configure**

When you run `cmake` add the additional parameter `-D OPENCV_GENERATE_PKGCONFIG=YES` e.g.

```
cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -D OPENCV_GENERATE_PKGCONFIG=YES -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local ..
```

Then `make` and `sudo make install` as before.

**Test**

Use the name `opencv4` instead of just `opencv` e.g.

```
pkg-config --cflags opencv4
```

Answer (score 4):

**Summary:**

This method downloads, extracts, compiles, and installs the latest OpenCV 4.0.1 manually. A working sample code `main.cpp` is also provided in order to demonstrate as proof of successful OpenCV installation.

> **What is OpenCV?**
>
> OpenCV is an image processing library created by Intel and later supported by Willow Garage and now maintained by Itseez, Inc. OpenCV means Intel® Open Source Computer Vision Library. It is a collection of C functions and a few C++ classes that implement some popular Image Processing and Computer Vision algorithms. OpenCV is Available on Mac, Windows, Linux (Terminal environment).

Follow the steps below to install OpenCV:

1. **Update Ubuntu 18.04.**

   Issue the following commands:

   ```
   $ sudo apt-get update
   $ sudo apt-get upgrade
   ```
2. **Install dependencies.**

   Issue the following command:

   ```
   $ sudo apt-get install build-essential cmake git libgtk2.0-dev pkg-config\
   libavcodec-dev libavformat-dev libswscale-dev python3.7 python3.7-dev python-numpy\
   python-scipy python-matplotlib ipython python-pandas python-sympy python-nose\
   libtbb2 libtbb-dev libjpeg-dev libpng-dev libtiff5-dev libjasper-dev\
   libdc1394-22-dev libeigen3-dev libtheora-dev libvorbis-dev libxvidcore-dev\
   libx264-dev sphinx-common libtbb-dev yasm libfaac-dev libopencore-amrnb-dev\
   libopencore-amrwb-dev libopenexr-dev libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-dev libavutil-dev\
   libavfilter-dev libavresample-dev
   ```
3. **Get OpenCV:** Download opencv 4.0.1 from [OpenCV Releases](https://opencv.org/releases.html) and opencv 4.0.1 testdata [opencv_extra-master.zip](https://github.com/opencv/opencv_extra/archive/master.zip).
4. **Extraction of OpenCV 4.0.1 zip package**

   Now that you’ve downloaded the correct archive package for your system into ***~/Downloads*** folder, run the following commands to extract OpenCV.

   ```
   $ sudo mkdir /opt/opencv
   ```

   To extract zip file `opencv-4.0.1.zip` into `/opt/opencv` folder, run the following command:

   ```
   $ sudo unzip ~/Downloads/opencv-4.0.1.zip -d /opt/opencv
   ```

   Now extract `opencv_extra-master.zip` which is a large file of size 490.3 MB which contain test suit needed to test `opencv 4.0.1`. Run the following command to complete extraction:

   ```
   $ sudo unzip ~/Downloads/opencv_extra-master.zip -d /opt/opencv/opencv-4.0.1
   ```
5. **Setup `symlink latest` pointing to current version opencv-4.0.1**

   Issue the following commands to create `symlink`:

   ```
   $ cd /opt/opencv
   $ sudo ln -s opencv-4.0.1 latest
   ```

   [image]

   **Why do you need symlink latest?**

   - `Symlink latest` always tracks current version of OpenCV installation.
   - Tomorrow, let us say, a new version 5.0.1 arrives, then install that
     version. Now you remove `symlink latest` pointing to older version
     4.0.1, by issuing the following command:

     ```
     $ sudo unlink /opt/opencv/latest
     ```

     'Symlink latest' points to current version opencv-4.0.1 but the arrival of newest version 5.0.1 causes to severe the 'symlink latest' from version 4.0.1.
   - Now create `symlink latest` pointing to newer version 5.0.1 with the
     following command:

     ```
     $ sudo ln -s opencv-5.0.1 latest
     ```

     Now 'symlink latest' points to newer version opencv-5.0.1. Please note that there is no such version called 5.0.1, this is just a 'fictional' one used to demonstrate the power of 'symlink latest'.
   - At the same time, you may still retain older version without removing
     them. For some reasons you want to work on an older version, you
     simply switch `symlink latest` pointing that older version and that
     is it! You don’t have to change any other settings.
   - In **step-8** subsequently, you will be setting up `PATH,
     LD_LIBRARY_PATH, PKG_CONFIG_PATH, and OPENCV_TEST_DATA_PATH`
     envirnement variables. The values of all these environment variables
     involve `symlink latest`, so that even later you switch pointing to
     newer version, these settings always remain untouched!
6. **Installation of `OpenCV 4.0.1` zip package**

   Create a temporary build directory `release`, which we denote as `<cmake_build_dir>`, where you want to put the generated Makefiles, project files as well the object files and output binaries and enter there.

   ```
   $ cd /opt/opencv/latest
   $ sudo mkdir release
   ```

   To build and install OpenCV, issue the following command:

   ```
   $ cd /opt/opencv/latest/release
   $ sudo cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DOPENCV_GENERATE_PKGCONFIG=YES -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/opt/opencv/opencv-4.0.1  /opt/opencv/opencv-4.0.1
   ```

   **Note:**

   - add this flag when running cmake: `-D OPENCV_GENERATE_PKGCONFIG=YES`
   - will generate the `.pc` file for `pkg-config` and install it.
   - useful if not using `cmake` in projects that use `OpenCV`.

   From build directory `release` execute `make`, it is recommended to do this in several threads:

   ```
   $ cd /opt/opencv/latest/release
   $ sudo make -j4                             # runs 4 jobs in parallel
   $ sudo make install
   ```

   To update the `links/cache` which the dynamic loader uses:

   ```
   $ sudo ldconfig
   ```
7. **Run testsuite locally for opencv-4.0.1**

   Before you begin test cases, `OPENCV_TEST_DATA_PATH` environment variable must be set.

   ```
   $ export OPENCV_TEST_DATA_PATH=/opt/opencv/latest/opencv_extra-master/testdata
   ```

   Issue the following commands to begin all the test cases:

   ```
   $ cd /opt/opencv/latest/release 
   $ sudo ./bin/opencv_test_core
   ```

   [image: Test case Core_globbing.accuracy failed]

   **Why did test case `Core_globbing.accuracy` failed?**

   We have just built our OpenCV Sources and tried to test the compilation by running `"./bin/opencv_test_core"` from `"/opt/opencv/latest/release"` folder.

   This testcase failed because there are no input images, therefore take any `.jpg` and `.png` pictures and rename these 2 pictures as `lena.jpg` and `lena.png` and copy them into `"/opt/opencv/latest/release/bin"` folder and re-run all the test cases again.

   Issue the following commands to re-run all the test cases again:

   ```
   $ cd /opt/opencv/latest/release 
   $ sudo ./bin/opencv_test_core
   ```

   [image: Test case passed]
8. **Setup PATH environment variable**

   OpenCV needs to set `PATH` environment variables which is to be set as shown below.

   Create a file called `opencv.sh` under `/etc/profile.d/` directory.

   ```
   $ sudo touch /etc/profile.d/opencv.sh
   $ sudo vi /etc/profile.d/opencv.sh
   ```

   Add the following contents:

   ```
   #!/bin/sh
   export PATH=/opt/opencv/latest/bin:/opt/opencv/latest/release/bin:${PATH}
   export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/opencv/latest/release/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
   export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/opt/opencv/latest/lib/pkgconfig
   export OPENCV_TEST_DATA_PATH=/opt/opencv/latest/opencv_extra-master/testdata
   ```

   Save and close the file. Make it executable using the following command.

   ```
   $ sudo chmod +x /etc/profile.d/opencv.sh
   ```

   Then, set the environment variables permanently by running the following command:

   ```
   $ source /etc/profile.d/opencv.sh
   ```

   **Log out or reboot your system.**

   Now, check the `PATH` environment variable:

   ```
   $ echo $PATH
   ```

   `PATH` environment variable should have `/opt/opencv/latest/bin` directory and `/opt/opencv/latest/release/bin` directory.
9. **Where is opencv4.pc?**

   Issue the following commands to locate `opencv4.pc`:

   ```
   $ sudo find /opt -name opencv4.pc
   ```

   opencv4.pc would be available in ***/opt/opencv/latest/lib/pkgconfig*** directory.

   Now, check the python3.7 version using command:

   ```
   $ python3.7 version
   ```

   **Where is `opencv_version` binary located?**

   Now, check the location of `opencv_version` using the following command:

   ```
   $ sudo updatedb                                      #  rebuild library cache
   $ locate opencv_version | grep bin/opecv_version
   ```

   opencv_version would be located in ***/opt/opencv/latest/release/bin*** directory.

   Now, check the `opencv_version` using command:

   ```
   $ opencv_version
   ```

   Now to check if `OpenCV` is installed on a machine, run the following commands:

   ```
   $ pkg-config --modversion opencv4
   ```

   [image]
10. **Sample testing:**

    - Create a folder `~/code` directory.
    - Save the following program as `main.cpp`
    - Move `main.cpp` into `~/code` directory
    - Add a `sample.jpg` under 1 MB size into `~/code` directory for testing.

    Issue the following commands:

    ```
    $ cd ~/code
    $ ls
    ```

    **Sample code:**

    ```cpp
    #include <opencv2/highgui.hpp>
    #include <iostream>

    int main( int argc, char** argv ) {

      cv::Mat image;
      image = cv::imread("sample.jpg" , cv::IMREAD_COLOR);

      if (! image.data ) {
          std::cout <<  "Could not open or find the image :";
          std::cout <<  "sample.jpg" << std::endl ;
          return -1;
      }

      cv::namedWindow( "Display window", cv::WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );
      cv::imshow( "Display window", image );

      cv::waitKey(0);
      return 0;
    }
    ```

    Compile `main.cpp`

    ```
    $ cd ~/code
    $ g++ main.cpp -o output `pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv4`
    ```

    Run `./output` as follows:

    ```
    $ ./output
    ```

    Output from the sample program `main.cpp`:

    [image]

Comment: Hey @Marmayogi!!! Please try to avoid unnecessary screenshots in your answer. If you have provided the command in the answer, that's sufficient. No need to add the picture of terminal running that command. This would effectively reduce the length of your answer and free of unnecessary things. I've edited your answer to remove extra things. If you feel some important screenshot is removed, feel free to rollback my edit.

Answer (score 0):

After building the library, you need to install it for it to be found without specifying the build directory.

```
sudo make install
```

This might solve your problem.

Comment: ive already done that, as part of the instructions, and also sudo ldconfig

Answer (score 0):

I found mine by running `sudo find / -name "opencv4.pc" 2>/dev/null` located in `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig/opencv4.pc`