# No package 'opencv4' found

Tags: software-installation, compiling, make, opencv

I have makefile has this line :

```
$(CLINAME): $(LIBNAME) main.c
    $(CC) -o $@ main.c -std=c99 `pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv4` -Iinclude -L. -l$@  -lm
```

I am trying to run my code but I got on this error when I write: make

```
Package opencv4 was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `opencv4.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'opencv4' found
```

How to fix that please?

Comment: No, sudo apt-get install python-opencv
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package python-opencv

Comment: I tried to follow these steps but I can unzip files https://askubuntu.com/questions/1127973/how-do-i-install-opencv4-0-on-18-10

Comment: @DanielT I don't think it's a duplicate of that question.

Answer (score 2):

OpenCV is available from the Ubuntu "universe" repository - unless you need a different version from that packaged for your distribution I suggest you install it via `apt` instead of from a 3rd party. The *development* metapackage is named `libopencv-dev` and its [current versions](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=libopencv-dev) are

> Package libopencv-dev
>
> ```
> focal (20.04LTS) (libdevel): development files for opencv [universe]
> 4.2.0+dfsg-5: amd64 arm64 armhf ppc64el riscv64 s390x
> jammy (22.04LTS) (libdevel): development files for opencv [universe]
> 4.5.4+dfsg-9ubuntu4: amd64 arm64 armhf ppc64el riscv64 s390x
> lunar (23.04) (libdevel): development files for opencv [universe]
> 4.6.0+dfsg-11: amd64 arm64 armhf ppc64el riscv64 s390x
> mantic (23.10) (libdevel): development files for opencv [universe]
> 4.6.0+dfsg-13build1: amd64 arm64 armhf ppc64el riscv64 s390x
> noble (libdevel): development files for opencv [universe]
> 4.6.0+dfsg-13build5: amd64 arm64 armhf ppc64el riscv64 s390x
> ```

Installing `libopencv-dev` will also install the dependent runtime libraries<sup>1</sup> and the `opencv4.pc` file for `pkg-config` support.

---

1. I'm not sure if it installs *all* OpenCV components or just the core ones, you'd need to parse through the output of `apt depends libopencv-dev` to be sure